# Produce product of lists

Tags: python, combinatorics, python-2.x

I want to combine elements in different lists.
For example, here are 3 lists.

```
list_a : [ 1,2,3 ]
list_b : [ 4,5,6 ]
list_c : [ 7,8 ]
```

Selecting elements from `list_b` and `list_c` is mutually exclusive.  When including an element from `list_b`, I'd like to also include an element from `list_bb`; when including an element from `list_c`, I'd like to also include an element from `list_cc`.

```
list_bb : [ 14,15,16 ]
list_cc : [ 17,18 ]
```

I wrote this code:

```
global sum_list=[]
for a in list_a:
    for b in list_b:
        for bb in list_bb:
            sum_list.append([a,b,bb])
for a in list_a:
    for c in list_c:
        for cc in list_cc:
           sum_list.append([a,c,cc])
```

Is there any better way to get the same result?

Answer (score 2):

The `itertools` library has a function called [`product`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). You can rewrite your snippet as:

```
global sum_list=itertools.product(list_a, list_b, list_bb) + itertools.product(list_a, list_c, list_cc)
```

If you don't want to use `itertools` (e.g. because you're stuck on python 2.4), you can also use a list comprehension:

```
global sum_list=[]
sum_list.extend([a,b,bb] for a in list_a for b in list_b for bb in list_bb)
sum_list.extend([a,c,cc] for a in list_a for c in list_c for cc in list_cc)
```